# How do I show all the UV maps on a single texture image?

Tags: texturing

I have a model consisting of several meshes. All of the textures are in a single image. When I unwrap a mesh I end up with a new UV map that I have to place somewhere on the image. This is something of a trial and error process, because at the moment I have an all white image and you can only she the outline of the UV map you're trying to place.

I can somewhat work around this by temporarily coloring the areas occupied by the other maps red or whatever, but it would be nice to have a way of displaying at least the outline of all the UV maps that apply to this image in the model. Does something like that exist?

(Note that this is probably mostly a result of me being a clueless noob with no sensible workflow, so I'm not going to be surprised if the answer is "don't do that!")

Comment: If I understand correctly this is what a UV checker texture would be used for - https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-m&biw=360&bih=612&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AOaemvJ7XmbnRc8pQGnmsZNZTMQzu7ALZg%3A1637349226895&sa=1&q=uv+test+graphic&oq=uv+test+graphic&aqs=mobile-gws-lite..#imgrc=2nnGdz9NFBI2UM

Comment: Are the meshes each separate objects, or are they all joined in one object?  If they are all separate objects, could you join them in one object?